# PHP AWS SDK returning different results than AWS CLI

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

Our organization's AWS setup is something like this:

```
Org
 -> Account 1
 -> Account 2
 -> Account 3
```

When logging in, we use oauth to get to the management console for the correct AWS account. For API based  access, I created an IAM role from within the account I am trying to query, and used the keys given to me as the credentials for the PHP sdk. Let's say the account I want to query is Account 2 (A2) and the account I am getting information from is Account 1 (A1).

Currently, I am trying to pull a list of ec2 instances with no filtering at all. I am doing this from a mezzio framework project within a docker container running on Ubuntu Focal for the OS. I am able to successfully query all of the EC2 instances from A1, even though my credentials were created for and from A2. When running the same query from the CLI, my results are from A2, as expected. The PHP code that I am using to initialize the EC2 client is below.

```
public function __construct($config)
{
    $this->client = new Ec2Client($config);
}
```

config looks like this:

```
[
    "region" => "us-east-1",
    "version" => "latest",
    "key" => $secrets['AwsKey'],
    "secret" => $secrets['AwsSecretKey']
]
```

AwsKey and AwsSecret get passed as environment variables, and are returned by a separate configuration class. My describeInstances call is relatively simple as well:

```
$instances = $this->client->describeInstances();
```

If there is something obvious I am missing here, please let me know. I imagine this is an issue on my end and not a defect within the SDK itself, but I wasn't able to find much information with my googling abilities, and the CLI vs PHP SDK output is much different.

Edit:

After some additional testing between the CLI and SDK with the owner-id filter, I am more inclined to believe this is a bug. I am unable to get instances with the correct owner-id using the SDK, but am able to do this with the CLI.